# Commenting on faulty code

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-policy

In this question, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107700/78136, the OP has not gotten the code to compile, and is on its way to be closed. This I understand, and are not debating.

My question, however, is whether it is according to site policy to give comments like the one I've given suggesting a missing brace. Or possibly comment other stuff which would make the code working, albeit possibly flawed, which in turn would render the question to be a legal question on Code Review. (And thus legible for reopening, if already closed)

**Added:** The icky part, for me, is that the correction does possibly encourage editing of code which is not something we want in general for a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should quick fixes to non-working code go into comments only?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/796/should-quick-fixes-to-non-working-code-go-into-comments-only)

Comment: The "possible duplicate" linked above, is from a time before the "working code" policy was "firmed up". As a result, it does not have the same answer/direction as this question does. The answer on that suggested-duplicate question is thus "not right" in the current context - it's not  a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comments are for that exact purpose - pointing out issues that need clarification in the question, or otherwise need to be addressed. Editing the code is not an option on Code Review. If it was a problem with the text I would just recommend an edit, otherwise.

So, yes, comment on the post, if/when the fix is applied, the question may be opened, and then your comment becomes obsolete, and may be removed.

This is the way it is designed to work.

Comment: I just hope this doesn't make people come here with broken code so that we can help them get it fixed by *posting SO-like answers in comments*...

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/796/should-quick-fixes-to-non-working-code-go-into-comments-only)